# What to do when a bounty asks a different question than the original question?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, bounties

This question [$_POST is not working in ajax form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672531/post-is-not-working-in-ajax-form-submit) had six answers  at the time the bounty was placed. The question has been answered in these answers.

[image]

This is the original question:

> When I try to check user input name is already exist by ajax form submit !But it only get Undefined index: username in sessions.php ,what is missing ?

This it the added question in the bounty:

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.
>
> explanation about contentType and processData usage in ajax

To me this is a similar issue to a question being edited to invalidate the current answers and this [How much change to the question is too much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much) gives instruction on how to handle that, except the question is being changed by using a bounty.

I have mod flagged the question:

[image]

Is this an acceptable use of the bounty feature?
Is a mod flag acceptable?
If not, what is the best course of action to take?

These questions are related but don't give an instruction on how best to handle this:
[Can a bounty ask to do things not directly related to the original question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120625/can-a-bounty-ask-to-do-things-not-directly-related-to-the-original-question?rq=1)
[How to ask for a different answer to an existing question? A bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103809/how-to-ask-for-a-different-answer-to-an-existing-question-a-bounty?rq=1)

Comment: I don't know if this specific case is actually a fitting example (maybe he just wanted some of the available responses to expand explaining the role of contentType an processData in the context of the original question? I don't know) but this is still something that may happen and probably has already happen. A bounty "different question" will live a short life and the problem will self resolve with its expiration, but in the meantime it can attract noise. It will be interesting to see if any mod has some actual data on the issue.

Comment: For information, the same question has been asked recently on EE'SE meta: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5807/what-to-do-when-bounty-asks-a-different-question. Answers there may be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mostly agree with the answers that have been made on a similar question on [EE.SE meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5807/what-to-do-when-bounty-asks-a-different-question).

Basically: it doesn't really matter. If a user offers a bounty and formulates something different in the bounty message, nobody should take that into account. The answers should consider what is formulated in the *question* only. Moreover, the bounty message disappears once the bounty is awarded, so it does not make sense to consider it.

Therefore, if the answerers shouldn't take the bounty message into account, it means that people offering bounty with a message deviating from the original question can't expect their specific requirements to be answered. And they basically wasted their rep for nothing. They should have asked another question instead, (eventually referencing the first if it makes sense, and explaining in which sense their question is different). *Then*, if it doesn't get answered as expected, offer a bounty on their *own* question.

Now, as to whether such invalid use of bounty must be flagged, I would say that it isn't really necessary. Moderators can indeed refund a bounty, but the only loser in the whole story is the person that set the bounty, anyway. So the best you can do in this situation is, I think, to simply raise an eyebrow for a second and move on with something else.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it there are two viable options, the reasons are elaborated below:

1. Edit the question to include the new bounty question.

   - If the bounty is posted by the OP and the question asked in the bounty does not invalidate current answers, the question should be edited to include the new bounty question, so when the bounty expires the answers will make sense.
2. Flag for moderator attention to have the bounty removed.

   - If the second question asked in the bounty invalidates existing answers
     *[How much change to the question is too much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much)

     [Is changing a question after a bounty was attached to it acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302566/is-changing-a-question-after-a-bounty-was-attached-to-it-acceptable)*
   - Or the bounty is placed by a user other than the OP and the bounty asks a question that changes the original question
     *[What do you do when a question gets hijacked for a bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314764/what-do-you-do-when-a-question-gets-hijacked-for-a-bounty?rq=1)*

Comment: Editing the original question would be a terrible option as there would be no other circumstance where that would be acceptable.

Comment: @Dom if it does not invalidate current answers there is no reason not to edit the original question. In fact people are encouraged to edit their posts to improve them (as long as it does not invalidate answers)

Comment: It leads down a bad path though for edits in general. Any edits should preserve the original question that the OP wanted and those editions take away from the original focus. I've seen question mutate after two or three good heated edits to something that the OP never asked for which could easily be the case if this is allowed to happen.

Comment: @Dom I totally agree with this premise, particularly if there are answers, it become a case of a vampire for help. I don't think bounties should be allowed to ask another or different question.